# How can I separate symbols [">", "<", ">=", "<="], numeric value and unit from a string by using regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I would like to separate symbols, numeric value and unit from a list of string by using regular expression.

```
    x = ">=40.55%"
```

Currently I try to use the following regex in Python to separate symbol, numeric value, and unit

```
    match = re.findall(r'^(\A[>|<])*(\d+[.]+\d+)*([%|mg/dl|cm2]\Z)',i)
```

But, it doesn't give the expected output.

Expected output:

```
    symbol = >=
    value = 40.55
    unit = %
```

Can I know how to use regular expression in Python to separate a string into symbol, numeric value and unit?

Comment: Brackets are not the same as parentheses; they do not group substrings. They basically define sets of single characters to match against *one* character.

Comment: Try `^(>=|<=|[<>])?(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)?(%|mg/dl|cm2)?`  https://regex101.com/r/P00kxK/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes about the pattern `^(\A[>|<])*(\d+[.]+\d+)*([%|mg/dl|cm2]\Z)` why it does not give the expected output:

- This `(\A[>|<])*` optionally repeats a single char being one of `>` `|` `<` at the start of the string, which will only match a single char at the most. The `\A` should be at the start of the pattern, and you should repeat the character class **inside** of the capture group
- This `[>|<]` does not match a `=` char
- This `[%|mg/dl|cm2]` does match the single `%` but it does not mean matching alternatives with the `|`, it is a character class matching one of `%` `|` `m` etc...
- This `(\d+[.]+\d+)*` Matches a mandatory decimal part, but note that repeating a capture group captures the value of the last iteration. So if you would have for example this string `>=40.55.2%` the capture group value would be 5.2

Example using named capture groups:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"\A(?P<symbol>[<>]=?)(?P<value>\d+(?:\.\d+)*)(?P<unit>%|mg/dl|cm2)\Z")
s = ">=40.55%"
m = pattern.match(s)
if m:
    print(m.groupdict())
```

Output

```
{'symbol': '>=', 'value': '40.55', 'unit': '%'}
```

The pattern explained:

```
\A(?P<symbol>[<>]=?)(?P<value>\d+(?:\.\d+)*)(?P<unit>%|mg/dl|cm2)\Z
```

- `\A` Start of string
- `(?P<symbol>[<>]=?)` Named group *symbol*, match one of `<` `>` and optional `=`
- `(?P<value>\d+(?:\.\d+)*)` Named group *value*, match 1+ digits and optionally repeat `.` and 1+ digits
- `(?P<unit>%|mg/dl|cm2)` Named group *unit*, match 1 of the alternatives
- `\Z` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g92YVi/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/TxpUSp)

Answer (score 3):

Below I made some assumptions about your format, for example that numbers like `.3` (to stand for `0.3`) are disallowed.

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'\A(=|<=|>=|<|>)(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(%|mg/dl|cm2)\Z')

x = ">=40.55%"
m = regex.match(x)
symbol, value, unit = m.groups()
# symbol: '>='
# value: '40.55'
# unit: '%'

# let's try to match a different string: "=-345mg/dl"
regex.match("=-345mg/dl").groups()
# output: ('=', '-345', 'mg/dl')
```

Here, `(?:...)` denotes a *non-capturing group*. Note that regex-initial `^` and regex-final `$` are respective synonyms of `\A` and `\Z` except in `MULTILINE` mode.

Check out the official [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

*Credit goes to user Pranav Hosangadi for suggesting to match an optional minus sign to capture negative numbers.*

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer that doesn't require you to pre-define the allowable units. Anything after the number is considered a unit.

Regex and explanation ([Try online](https://regex101.com/r/20X1Ci/1)):

```
^([<>]=?)(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(.*)$
-------------------------------
^                             $ : Start and end of string or line
 (      )(               )(  )  : Capturing groups for each portion of the string
  [<>]                          : Less than or greater than symbol
      =?                        : Optional equal symbol
          -?                    : Optional minus sign
            \d+                 : One or more digits
               (?:     )?       : Optional non-capturing group
                  \.\d+         : Decimal point followed by one or more digits
                           .*   : Any number of any character
```

Code:

```
result = re.findall(r"^([<>]=?)(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(.*)$", ">=40.55%")
if result:
    symbol, value, unit = result[0]
```

which gives:

```
symbol = '>='
value = '40.55'
unit = '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
match = re.findall(r'(?:\A|\s)(=|<=|>=)(\d+\.\d+)(\%|mg/dl|cm2)(?:\Z|\s)',i)
```

matches `xx.x`

```
match = re.findall(r'(?:\A|\s)(=|<=|>=)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(\%|mg/dl|cm2)(?:\Z|\s)',i)
```

matches `xx.x` and `xx`, f.e. `i = "something >=40.55% or =30cm2 etc."` ==> result: `[('>=', '40.55', '%'), ('=', '30', 'cm2')]`